# CUDA cross-compiling error! cuda-gdb error message RSEG1058

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, cross-compiling, cuda-gdb

I'm new in this CUDA and parallel computing staff and I have a recent problem. I have an Ubuntu 12.04 system which is host and Jetson TK1 as the target. I'm using Nsight Eclipse to write, edit and compile the algorithms. I'm using SSH protocol to connect TK1 from the host computer.

When I try some file transfer operations it's okay always. However, sometimes the cross-compiling process sucks and errors "Connect to ubuntu@192.168.0.94 was cancelled" having title "RSEG1058". I don't understand the problem because this problem occurs 75% of the time. Sometimes it works perfectly. Can you help me please? I can give another info if it's needed. BY the way, I also found another possibly problematic detail. When I try to change the configuration of the run from the option "Run Configurations" found in the arrow near the RUN button, I discovered that we can change the library and toolkit path which is set in the first place. What I saw in that window was that cuda-gdb file has a red-cross icon with "Operation failed. File system input or output error" message. You can see the image and understand what I'm talking about. I don't know whether these two things are related or not, but I'm tired to try to catch the perfect timing all the time.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like something you should take up with the vendor via their support channels.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug. It was root caused to one of the Ubuntu patches against openssh-6.6p1. Ubuntu openssh bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1334916 has the details. NSight Eclipse Edition has worked around this bug by avoiding creating multiple ssh sessions which will be available in 6.5RC if you are registered developer you will get access to 6.5RC bits.

Answer (score 2):

Try stopping dbus daemon (by issuing "sudo dubs stop") on the TK1 board or recompiling sshd without ConsoleKit integration.