# Cross-Debugging RSEG1058 Connect to 192.168.XXX.XXX cancelled

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging, ssh, gdb

I am using eclipse mars for remote debugging with ssh. The first attempt always works. After disconnect the device, eclipse has got a problem connecting again.

Then often (not always) I get the fault: 
**RSEG1058** `Connect to 192.168.XXX.XXX cancelled`

Looking through `ps` , I recognized there are unclosed `sftp` processes on the target device.

```
/usr/lib/sftp-server
```

Further information:

- Ubuntu 14. on VirtualBox
- Eclipse Mars
- SSH connection for remote debugging
- arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb (7.6.2)

Could anybody explain, what is happening here and how to solve it??

================== UPDATE: ===============================================
It seems to be this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1334916

A possible workaround would be to compile openssh without consolekit.patch, but how to do that????:
https://superuser.com/questions/962319/compiling-openssh-without-consolekit-patch

This question is probably similar, but also with no solution:
[CUDA cross-compiling error! cuda-gdb error message RSEG1058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185946/cuda-cross-compiling-error-cuda-gdb-error-message-rseg1058)

also no Solution http://www.codegur.net/25301043/remote-debugging-c-with-eclipse-cdt-leads-to-rseg20158-connect-to-xxx-was-ca